# Keeping the URL but changing the site - How?

Tags: site-url

I'm trying to move a wordpress site to the new URL from new.XX.nl to XX.nl for someone else.
I changed the URL in wordpress in the new site, but it only resulted in me being unable to login into any wp-admin from either site and the site itself still shows the old site (without any CSS or theme).

I was wondering what I did wrong. I read somewhere I still needed to rename files in DirectAdmin, but I can't even find the new/old site in the directories. I did find the folder "new" in the public_html folder but the content is the same as public_html, but without the "new"-folder.

And I know it's better to have someone who knows stuff about this, but he quit and aside from him no one really knows what to do now.
Could someone please help me? It's very frustrating because the site is just breaking.

So my concrete questions would be:
- Where can I find the new site?
- How do I prevent CSS from breaking?

Comment: You should follow the instructions here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: [Search, and research](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking your question. Google query is 20 characters long, your question is 900 characters long.

Comment: I have. But apparently I did something wrong while following the instructions because it's not working now, hence I'm asking what I did wrong and how I can fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
this plugin will come to rescue. I have migrated/transferred over 100s of WP websites with this superb plugin without having any problem. It easy, secure and helps in productivity. It will change all the urls which is necessary to be changed during migration, so after migration you don't have to manually go into the code/db with change it. It does everything by himself.
Hope it helps.

Comment: So the best thing to do is restore a backup and then just start from scratch?

Comment: This is not from scratch, but you can say it as best practices to deploy or migrating a website from dev to production mode, or building a new copy of exisiting website to new domain.